# Laravel FORM::select not being displayed in webpage

Tags: forms, laravel, select

when creating the register page I am trying to pass in an array from the database ('id' and 'name') into a select field box on the register form but it wont display anything, its really bazar, when I inspect it in the browser I can see the div container and all of the options correctly in proper fields but for some reason there is no select field (total not visible in the browser) lol, I tried it with hard coded values and values from db and nothing is getting the select field to work, any help is greatly appreciated!

[image: select field]

[image]

login.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('content')
    <div class="page-footer" id="contactus">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" align="center">
                <div class="col 16 s12">
                    <h4 class="black-text">Account Center</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
                <div class="col 16 s12 m6" align="center">
                    <h5 class="black-text">Login</h5>
                    {!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=>'UsersController@store', 'class'=>'pure-form pure-form-stacked']) !!}
                    <br/>
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix fa fa-at"></i>
                        {!! Form::label('loginEmail', 'E-mail') !!}
                        {!! Form::email('loginEmail', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-field">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix fa fa-key"></i>
                        {!! Form::label('loginPassword', 'Password') !!}
                        {!! Form::password('loginPassword', ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::button('<i class="material-icons left fa fa-send"></i>Login', ['type' => 'submit', 'class'=>'waves-effect waves-light btn']) !!}
                    </div>

                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                    <br/><br/>
                </div>

                <div class="col 16 s12 m6" align="center">
                    <h5 class="black-text">Register</h5>
                    {!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=>'UsersController@store', 'class'=>'pure-form pure-form-stacked']) !!}
                    <br/>
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix fa fa-at"></i>
                        {!! Form::label('registerEmail', 'E-mail') !!}
                        {!! Form::email('registerEmail', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-field">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix fa fa-key"></i>
                        {!! Form::label('registerPassword', 'Password') !!}
                        {!! Form::password('registerPassword', ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-field">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix fa fa-key"></i>
                        {!! Form::label('confirm', 'Confirm Password') !!}
                        {!! Form::password('confirm', ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-field">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix fa fa-building"></i>
                        {!! Form::label('role_id', 'Role') !!}
                        </br>
                        {!! Form::select('role_id', [''=>'Choose Option'] + $organizationTypes, null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'style'=>' resize:vertical; ', 'id' => 'industryId'])!!}
                    </div>
                    </br>
                    </br>
                    </br>
                    </br>

                    <div class="input-field">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix fa fa-building"></i>
                        {!! Form::label('organizationName', 'Organization Name') !!}
                        {!! Form::password('organizationName', ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::button('<i class="material-icons left fa fa-send"></i>Register', ['type' => 'submit', 'class'=>'waves-effect waves-light btn']) !!}
                    </div>

                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                        <!-- loading spinner -->
                        <div class="preloader-wrapper active" id="sendEmailLoader">
                            <div class="spinner-layer spinner-yellow-only">
                                <div class="circle-clipper left">
                                    <div class="circle"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="gap-patch">
                                    <div class="circle"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="circle-clipper right">
                                    <div class="circle"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <!-- end loader -->
                    </form>
                    <br/><br/>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
@endsection
```

AuthController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\OrganizationType;
use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/users';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => array(
                'required',
                'min:6',
                'confirmed',
                'regex:/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*(_|[^\w])).+$/'
            ),
            'organizationType' => 'required',
            'organizationName' => 'required|max:255',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }

    public function getLogin()
    {
        //
        $organizationTypes = OrganizationType::lists('name','id')->all();
        //return $organizationTypes;
        return view('auth.login', compact('organizationTypes'));
    }
}
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

method lists() is deprecated, use pluck() instead.

to get your select do this:

In your controller first change lists() to pluck() (i hope you have laravel version 5.2+)

```
$organizationTypes = OrganizationType::pluck('name','id')->toArray();
```

and in view do this

```
{!! Form::select('role_id', $organizationTypes, null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
```

#### update

OK you are using css template materialize and because of template you need to append right class for select box...this will work but probably needs some other classes too:

```
{!! Form::select('role_id', $organizationTypes, null, ['class' => 'browser-default', 'placeholder' => 'Choose Option'])!!}
{!! Form::label('role_id', 'Organization name') !!}
```

Comment: Yes im using laravel version 5.2 :). Thank you for pointing out the deprecated information! I also tried your fix and still no luck :/ I'll post a photo on my question to hopefully help people understand my question more, and even with the lists() and pluck() method I can verify that I am retrieving the correct information from just returning the array but the select field itself is not being displayed :(.

Comment: I hope you copied my email

Comment: Not too sure what your referring to but I did copy your code and tried it in mine :), I did not have any different results.

Comment: ok got it. not sure why we are gonna email tho lol, its best if we do it here so hopefully we can help others with the same issue.

Comment: Yes true, but you have probably done some small mistake and i would like to see it .... so if i help you we will post this here

Comment: ok great thank you but not too sure what I will be able to provide you with since this is on a private development server :(

Comment: OK then try first to `dd($organizationTypes);` in your controller right before returning the view. You should get an array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136439/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-rapid3642).

Comment: Thank you so much! you nailed it!